# PHP XML escaping conversion issue

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I am using simplexml_load_file function to load two files into PHP.
Both files have the same structure but different content.
What I basically plan to achieve is copying one node from the one tree to another.
Since I have conditions where I first have to read the values etc, I decided to go for two FOR loops, which looks like this:

```
foreach ($xml1->node as $obj1 => $value2) { //input entries
foreach ($xml2->node as $obj2 => $value2) { //update entries
```

This is more a theoretically question to understand, it is really hard to post the full case.
If I now want to copy the content of node of XML1 to XML2 (in other words I want to replace node XML2), this should be in theory really easy to achieve:

```
$xml2->node = $xml1->node;
```

Somehow this does not fly. It displays nothing.
I ve tried a lot and my best result came out doing this:

```
$xml2->node = $xml1->node->asXML();
```

For any reason the copied content then gets encoded with & lt ; and & gt ; instead of < and > signs.
What am I am doing wrong? I really just want to copy one node with the same structure from one tree to another.

Comment: you can't assign members of one dom object to another. you have to import them first: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php

Comment: Could you please make an example from the XML1 and XML2 trees i was talking about? I m afraid I do not fully understand do you mean?